# DevExpress DataGrid filter cell triggers SelectedItem change

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, devexpress

I have a DevExpress WPF datagrid and the SelectedItem is used via Binding in the ViewModel.

When I select a row, it loads data in a detail view.

However, when I select a filter cell, it also triggers the SelectedItem binding and it tries to load...well, nothing as there is no real row selected.

[image]

I intend to use the filter as the following: the SelectedItem is the *first* item in the *filtered* list.

How can I prevent the filter cell from triggering the SelectedItem change and make my first item as the selected one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the SelectedItem's Binding with an

```
     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

the default UpdateSourceTrigger for all binding's inside a DataGrid is LostFocus.
that's why your item is updated when leaving the row , it lost it's focus.

Please check syntax since it was not written in VisualStudio .

```
 <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding YourItem,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, the click inside the filter cell does change the selected item.